# Generate polygons such that the image is filled

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I would like to generate n polygons, say 50 such that they fill up all of a given image, say 300x300 pixels.

I would also like each of the polygons to be 2 dimensional triangles, i.e. the random picking process should not pick 3 points on the same line in y or x.

Here is my solution so far

```
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw
import PIL.Image as Image
import random
import numpy as np

dimensions = (300, 300)
img = Image.new('RGB', dimensions)

polygons = [[tuple(np.random.randint(low=0, high=dimensions[1] + 1, size=2)) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(50)]

drw = ImageDraw.Draw(img, 'RGBA')
for i in range(50):
    random_numbers = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=(50, 3))
    generated_colours = [tuple(colour + [128]) for colour in random_numbers.tolist()]
    drw.polygon(polygons[i], generated_colours[i])
del drw

img.show()
```

This generates 50 translucent polygons, but they do not fill the shape and it allows the creation of a polygon which is essentially a line.

How can I achieve what I want?

EDIT: Also I wanted to generate the polygons in a more efficient way, but for some reason.

```
polygons = np.random.randint(low=0, high=dimensions[1], size=(50, 3, 2))
```

doesn't work.

EDIT2: I think I have solved the issue of making lines, however I think perhaps the efficiency can be improved

```
polygons = []
for i in range(50):
    coordinates = [[-1, -1], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]]
    for j in range(3):
        new_coordinates = tuple(np.random.randint(low=0, high=300 + 1, size=2))
        while new_coordinates[0] in [coordinates[0][0], coordinates[1][0], coordinates[2][0]] or new_coordinates[1] in [coordinates[0][1], coordinates[1][1], coordinates[2][1]]:
            new_coordinates = tuple(np.random.randint(low=0, high=300 + 1, size=2))
        coordinates[j] = new_coordinates
    polygons.append(coordinates)
```

Comment: What should the result look like please? How about drawing a really big one first then you'd cover the shape?

Comment: @Mark Setchell it should fill it with triangles such that you cannot see the background anymore. Perhaps, but that sort of defeats the point.

Comment: Apart from degeneracy which you have to address separately, Delaunay triangulation should essentially do what you want. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html

Comment: @PaulPanzer How can I use that to produce polygons in PIL?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Actually I don't think Delaunay helps at all. I want the shapes to overlap.

Comment: You are right, my bad. How about starting with a regular tiling and then randomly grow the triangles? Or if that looks bad, do start with Delaunay and then grow the triangles. You could grow ABC by adding a positive combination of A-B and A-C to A and similarly for B and C.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Honestly I'm not sure exactly. I am trying to replicate the Mona Lisa genetic algorithm project.

Comment: @PaulPanzer A Delaunay background with randomly placed triangles on top of it sounds like a good idea. However, I can't work out how to produce a Delaunay pattern in PIL.

Comment: You'd randomly draw 52 points inside your rectangle (or maybe a sligtly larger rectangle), pass those to the `Delaunay` constructor (from the scipy module I mentioned above) retrieve the `simplices` attribute and use it to index into points. This gives you a list of triangles (a 50x3x2 or some permutation of that array).

Comment: @PaulPanzer Is this what you meant https://pastebin.com/ah97chfM? It does not produce what you described.

Comment: @PaulPanzer This code is disgusting, but it works https://pastebin.com/uHkK5GB9. Except it doesn't quite cover the image.

Comment: How do you want the image covered? Are triangles allowed to be partly outside the image? If not just include the four corners (plus, if you like, some random points on the edges) in your initial list of random points. If yes, either do the same and shift the added points a random bit outside or draw your points from a larger rectangle (somthing like `randint(-padding,maxcoord+padding,...`)

Comment: Btw. I don't know that Mona Lisa thing you mentioned. Does it require some specific kind of randomness?

Comment: @PaulPanzer This is the idea https://rogerjohansson.blog/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa. Although I'm using a slightly different implementation in that I'm using triangles and it seems like he built them up rather than generating 50 at the start.

Comment: I think I'll have to stick with the original idea, whereby I generate 50 triangles that are guaranteed to be within the image. I guess I can accept some influence of the background colour.

Comment: I quickly glanced at the link and it looks to me as if the shapes of the polygons also evolve, so even if your triangles do not initially cover the image there should be some selection pressure to make them over time. Unless you explicitly want to keep the shapes fixed and only want to change the colors. But then unless you have a highly nonlinear color mixing model, this is just a constrained linear minimization, and I don't know genetic algorithms are considered good for that.